# Select function in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**My php file**

```
$option1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if(isset($option1) && !empty(option1)) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM fantasy WHERE os_id='$option1'";
}
```

**My ajax**

```
function filter(){
   var str = $("#advanced-search1").val();
   $.ajax({
     dataType: 'html',
     url: "filter.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {"key": str},
     success: function(response){
         $('#result').html(response);
     }
   });
}
```

From the above, stated that my select function id is **#advanced-search1** whereas my submit button would be **onclick="filter()"**. But it still doesn't work for me to execute the sql command in my php file. From my url browser, it stated the required select value, but it doesn't show anything in my **#result** div

Comment: you need to understand what `submit` button will do - and stop it from doing so if you want to use ajax - or simply have a button that doesn't submit to run the filter function

Comment: "simply have a button that doesn't submit to run the filter function" -how to do that?

Comment: Console log the response that u get on success. Do u get any data in response ?

Comment: yes i want to retrieve the data from response @jagrati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning of filter function :

```
function filter(event){

    event.preventDefault();

   var str = $("#advanced-search1").val();
   $.ajax({
     dataType: 'html',
     url: "filter.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {"key": str},
     success: function(response){
         $('#result').html(response);
     }
   });
}
```

However, you need to  change the call also to pass the event argument :

```
<button onclick="filter(event);" >..</button>
```

Instead of :

```
<button onclick="filter();" >..</button>
```

If does not work , you have to report your PHP log as well as your HTML skeleton.

Comment: oh thank god, you're awesome. I got another question, how can i pass two variable from the 2 select id?